# how to store only one value on my django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

below is my model

```
from django.db import models
LEVEL_CHOICES = (('beg','beginner'),('ind','inter'),('exp','expert'))
class scrap(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=True)
    # level= models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES)
    time = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

is there anyway so that i can only store one value per class.what i am doing is supplying values to this model's  objects through a form.so i want only once instance of this class.if another value is supplied through through the form,what i want is the old value to be replaced and new value to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you really just keep one object for your model, but it's pretty easy to achieve:

```
if scrap.objects.exists():
    current_scrap = Scrap.objects.all()[0]
else:
    current_scrap = Scrap()
current_scrap.subject = new_subject
current_scrap.level = new_level
current_scrap.time = new_time
current_scrap.save()
```

Comment: didnt worked. i am actually new to django and i dont know where exactly i am supposed to put that code above?